# Multiple Search and Replace

Tags: find-and-replace

In some of my projects I have to do extensive find and replace on plain text files before I begin to work with the file.

(Just to give an idea: I often have edit bridge (card game) related files I need to convert, say 1♣ to one club; over that I need to convert certain expressions to hyphenated form, say 1♣ opening becomes one club opening, and that becomes one-club opening. All in all, I need to do close to two-hundred operations.)

Up to now, I saved my find and replace strings and did multiple find and replace in Notepad++. (e.g., FIND: (FindA)|(FindB)|(FindC)... REPLACE:
(?1ReplaceA)(?2ReplaceB)(?3ReplaceC)...)

Now, I feel that even that approach is slow.

What other options do I have?

Is the solution to write a program in some language (I know a little Python, barely taking care of myself) to process the text? Is there an especially suitable language for the job. I would think of it as a long shot, but is there a software/tool especially suited for the job?

(Working on Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit.)

Comment: Use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

Comment: Easiest option could be to record a macro in notepad++. "Is the solution to write a program..." - this paragraph makes your question off-topic, being too broad / asking for product recommendation ...

Comment: I'd really recommend using excel to 'generate' the `FIND & REPLACE` list. Where (in excel) the list/sequence is easily modifiable.